# misc_controls_deviceorientation.html works in Android Firefox but not Chrome on Androi

Tags: android, google-chrome, firefox, server, device-orientation

I tried this example on the threejs.org website and it works beautifully on both Chrome and Firefox on Android:

https://threejs.org/examples/misc_controls_deviceorientation.html

However, once I install three.js on other servers (local or online), the above code only works in Android Firefox, and not Android Chrome (the image does not pan).

Is there something I should set in the server to correct this?

Many thanks for your help